# GMAIL API : Authorize Every time you use the API

Tags: gmail-api

Do you need to Authorize everytime before calling any Gmail API?

I have done authorization once and got the access Token and Refresh Token.

If I call the API's every minute for a user, do I need to Refresh the tokens everytime? If not, when should I do it again?

Answer (score 0):

The access token is valid for one hour then you can use the refresh token to get a new access token without having the user to grant permissions again.

you can use the refresh token whenever you want to get a new access token, although it would be better to use it just before the access token expires.

Here is more [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) on that.

Comment: I have gone through the documentation.However the strange thing is that although the token expires after 1 hour, it continues to work.

I get a new Token at start up of my application and it continues to work even after 12 hours.